# How can there be a non-covariant exterior derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

So, if I'm not wrong, the definition of the exterior derivative of a differential $k$-form is the differential $k\text{+}1$-form

$$\text{d}\omega = \omega_{i_1...i_k,i_{k+1}} \text{d}x^{i_{k\text{+}1}}\wedge\text{d}x^{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge\text{d}x^{i_k}.$$

When I was introduced to the concept of the covariant derivative, I was told that the partial derivative (the one used to define the exterior derivative of differential forms) doesn't produce objects whose components transform as tensor components would under a change of basis, so... how does that not contradict the idea of the exterior derivative mapping differential $k$-forms to differential $k\text{+}1$-forms? Am I missing something or am I using wrong definitions?

Comment: 1. The exterior derivative is independent of the covariant derivative. The second one needs a connection, while the first one only relies on the differentiable structure of the manifold.
2. Your formula is not right. Either you need a partial derivative, some factors, or the order of the basis forms is wrong. Have you checked [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative)?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz My formula was wrong, sorry! But it doesn't lack a partial derivative because it is there represented with the comma in the subscripts.

Comment: The exterior derivative is well defined, ie independent of coordinate chart, because you are anti-symmetrizing the sum.

Comment: Dear @s.harp could you explain intuitively why antisymmetrization leads to chart independence?

Comment: @Arrow if you know the reason why $\partial_i f_j$ does not transform correctly  under basis change its because you get an additional unwanted term of the form $\partial_{i'}( \partial_{j'}x^j) f_j$ which comes from the product rule. As you likely know $\partial_{i'}\partial_{j'}x^j(x^{k'})$ is symmetric in $i', j'$, so if you anti-symmetrize the indexes $i'$ and $j'$ this term dies and everything transforms correctly. You can do this with every index that appears, but you need to anti-symmetrize all of these with the $\partial_{i'}$.

Comment: Now its possible I may have messed up where the $'$ go and so on, but thats the basic idea. Doing the calculation correctly and explicitly will make it clear.

Comment: Dear @s.harp thank you for the proof sketch! I am more curious whether there is a geometric interpretation of antisymmetrization which might also make chart independence morally transparent.

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason that could be described as geometric. One thing you could look at is that the exterior derivative is the notion of derivative you need to make stokes formula right. Here $d\circ d=0$ is a consequence of the statement "the boundary of a boundary is empty". Since $d\circ d = 0$ expresses that taking derivatives makes things anti-symmetric, you could view "a boundary has no boundary" as a geometric reason for the anti-symmetry. Another thing you could try is to find a geometric reason partial derivatives commute then push this reason to the considerations here.

Comment: @Arrow well, when first discussing the relationship between the determinant and the area of a parallelogram (or t volume of a paralellepiped), it is said that the determinant is requiered to be alternating (which implies antisymmetry) because the area of a parallelogram is 0 whenever two sides of a parallelogram coincide.
As differential forms are exterior forms (just like the determinant) and antisymmetrization is requiered for the exterior derivative of a differential form to be itself a differential form, maybe there's a way to bring that geometric interpretation to exterior derivatives.